# Is there a way to tell geoserver to send cp1250 http header?

Tags: geoserver

I'm running geoserver with some web pages in data_dir/www. These pages
are encoded in cp1250, but when I load them using geoserver
(localhost:8080/geoserver/www) they are encoded or they behave as they
were encoded in utf-8. As a result i get tons of question marks
instead of real letters.

I am not able to convert pages into utf-8, so is there a way to tell
geoserver not to send utf-8 http header and send cp1250 header
instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is a global setting for charsets here:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/server/globalsettings.html

That said, I'm not sure if it will help for pages in the www directory or if it will have side effects on OGC requests and GUI pages (as far as I know at that point you need everything to be in that charset)

Comment: Already tried, it doesn't affect web pages served by geoserver.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that without coding there is no way to change it. The class to be modified is the AbstractURLPublisher in the ows module. If you have coding abilities please fork GeoServer on github, make it use the globally configured charset, and issue a pull request.

Comment: I don't know much about java, it's gonna be easier to convert these pages to utf-8 then. Thank you.